# Applet to view Word documents

Tags: java, ms-word, applet

How to open a Word document in IE without open / save dialog in java applet?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a signed applet that loads the MS Word ActiveX control using a Java-COM bridge. FWIW, I've used ComfyJ, a commercial Java JNI library to do this. Obviously it only works on Windows client computers that have MS Word installed already. The very idea of it sends shivers down my spine, however...it is almost certainly a Bad Idea.